# Wrapping method to make it generic with map method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, functional-programming

I have a method that looks more or less like this:

```
ConcreteType Find(IEnumerable<ConcreteType> values)
```

It iterates an `IEnumerable` and at some point will return one of the values contained as a result. This method is not under my control and I cannot change it.

I need to wrap this method in another method that should look like this:

```
T Find(IEnumerable<T> values, Func<T,ConcreteType> map)
```

Having a generic type `T`. This method should call the method above by mapping all values from `T` to the `ConcreteType` and then later map the `ConcreteType` that was returned back to the original `T`.

What is the easiest way to do this?

**Important:** The enumerable is evaluated dynamically (LINQ) and the `map` method can be slow. So the solution is not allowed to iterate the enumerable more than the original `Find` has to do and the map method should also only be called for values that are actually requested by the original `Find` method.

You can assume that all values (`T` or `ConcreteType`) are unique so there is no possibility of one `ConcreteType` mapping to various `T` or vice versa.

**Example:**

If the above is too abstract, here is an concrete example:

```
// Original method
byte[] FindMatchingBuffer(IEnumerable<byte[]> values)

// Wrapper (TODO)
T FindMatchingBuffer(IEnumerable<T> values, Func<T, byte[]> map)

// Sample call
string matchingFileName = FindMatchingBuffer(fileNames, File.ReadAllBytes);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the method you can't change will only iterate as far as it needs to? In other words, can you return the last value that it fetched?

Comment: @JonSkeet I know the method will only iterate as far as it needs to. So, yes I could return the last value catched. Although I think such a solution would feel a bit dirty to me...

Comment: You're inherently in a dirty situation, I'd say. Do you have any guarantees that you can compare instances of `ConcreteType` for equality? Is it a problem to store all the mapped instances of `ConcreteType` in memory? In the example you've given, both of these are a pain - you presumably wouldn't want to keep all the data of all the files you'd read.

Comment: Yes, I know the instances of ConcreteType as I'm "producing" them myself and the presumed "contract" of the method is that it will always return an item in the list or null. ConcreteTypes will all be distinct and can be compared by reference. No need to compare by value.

Comment: Also, although having to keep data in memory is not nice, but it won't be a problem as the complete sum of all values is expected to be less than a few megabytes and I'm already caching some of these values anyway as loading them is expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is equivalent to that of C.Evenhuis, but uses an iterator block instead of a whole separate class:

```
T Find(IEnumerable<T> values, Func<T, ConcreteType> map)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<ConcreteType, T>();
    ConcreteType found = Find(MapAndRecord(values, map, reverseMapping));
    // TODO: Handle the situation where it's not found. (Does Find
    // return null?)
    return dictionary[found];
}

private static IEnumerable<ConcreteType> MapAndRecord(
    IEnumerable<T> values, Func<T, ConcreteType> map,
    IDictionary<ConcreteType, T> reverseMapping)
{
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        var mapped = map(value);
        reverseMapping[mapped] = value;
        yield return mapped;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `IEnumerator<Y>` (`byte[]` in your example) that takes an `IEnumerator<T>` and the map function as constructor arguments, and keep a `Dictionary` of all mapped items (as we don't know whether `Find` stops iterating after finding the match).

After `Find` returns you can `TryGetInputValue` to get the filename again.

(I'm not a LINQ user but I'm sure this can be wrapped into something LINQable)

```
public sealed class LookupEnumerator<T, Y> : IEnumerator<Y>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> input;
    private readonly Func<T, Y> map;
    private readonly Dictionary<Y, T> reverse = new Dictionary<Y, T>();

    public LookupEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> input, Func<T, Y> map)
    {
        this.input = input;
        this.map = map;
    }

    public Y Current
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public bool TryGetInputValue(Y value, out T inputValue)
    {
        return reverse.TryGetValue(value, out inputValue);
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (!input.MoveNext())
        {
            return false;
        }

        Current = map(input.Current);
        reverse.Add(Current, input.Current);
        return true;
    }

    // ... rest of IEnumerator implementation
```

Comment: Yes, this would definitily work. I was looking for something simpler though which does not require a whole enumerator implementation...